# Ansible. Duplication of task execution

Tags: ansible

Simple playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ulogin: login
    upasswd: passwd
    user_login_with_password:
      - user_login: "{{ ulogin }}"
        user_passwd: "{{ upasswd }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ item.user_login }} -- {{ item.user_passwd }}"
      when: item.user_passwd != None
      loop: "{{ user_login_with_password }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.user_login }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=login) => {
    "msg": "login -- passwd"
}
```

Everything is fine!

---

We remove the password:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ulogin: login
    upasswd: 
    user_login_with_password:
      - user_login: "{{ ulogin }}"
        user_passwd: "{{ upasswd }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ item.user_login }} -- {{ item.user_passwd }}"
      when: item.user_passwd != None
      loop: "{{ user_login_with_password }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.user_login }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************
skipping: [host1] => (item=login) 
skipping: [host1]
```

**Why a double action "skiping" appears???**

P.S.
Verbose output:

```yaml
skipping: [host1] => (item=login)  => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": {
        "user_login": "login",
        "user_passwd": null
    }
}
skipping: [host1] => {
    "msg": "All items skipped"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a double action. The last message says all items in the loop were skipped. For example, given the simplified list with more items

```yaml
    user:
      - passwd: 
      - passwd: 
      - passwd:
```

The debug task

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item.passwd
      loop: "{{ user }}"
      when: item.passwd != None
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None}) 
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None}) 
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None}) 
skipping: [host1]
```

, or more verbose (-v)

```yaml
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None})  => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  false_condition: item.passwd != None
  item:
    passwd: null
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None})  => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  false_condition: item.passwd != None
  item:
    passwd: null
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None})  => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  false_condition: item.passwd != None
  item:
    passwd: null
skipping: [host1] => 
  msg: All items skipped
```

You see the last message `msg: All items skipped` because the [developers decided to report it](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py#L158)

```python
     if res['skipped']:
         res['msg'] = 'All items skipped'
```

See the registered variable

```yaml
  out:
    changed: false
    msg: All items skipped
    results:
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      false_condition: item.passwd != None
      item:
        passwd: null
      skip_reason: Conditional result was False
      skipped: true
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      false_condition: item.passwd != None
      item:
        passwd: null
      skip_reason: Conditional result was False
      skipped: true
    - ansible_loop_var: item
      changed: false
      false_condition: item.passwd != None
      item:
        passwd: null
      skip_reason: Conditional result was False
      skipped: true
    skipped: true
```

The value of `out.skipped` is *true* because all items were skipped. Otherwise, the value will be *false* and the last `skipping: [host1]` will be missing. For example,

```yaml
     user:
      - passwd: a
      - passwd: b
      - passwd:
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [host1] => (item={'passwd': 'a'}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    passwd: a
  item.passwd: a
ok: [host1] => (item={'passwd': 'b'}) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item:
    passwd: b
  item.passwd: b
skipping: [host1] => (item={'passwd': None})
```

You can avoid this complexity. The best practice is to select items in the list instead of testing a condition on each iteration. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item.passwd
      loop: "{{ user | selectattr('passwd') }}"
      register: out
```

In the case all *passwd* are None, you'll see the simple report

```yaml
skipping: [host1]
```

and registered variable

```yaml
  out:
    changed: false
    results: []
    skipped: true
    skipped_reason: No items in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

If use lists of ssh-keys, can do this:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ulogin1: login1
    usshkeys1: [sshkey1]
    ulogin2: login2
    usshkeys2: []
    ulogin3: login3
    usshkeys3:
      - sshkey31
      - sshkey32
      - sshkey33
    user_login_with_sshkeys:
      - user_login: "{{ ulogin1 }}"
        ssh_keys: "{{ usshkeys1 }}"
      - user_login: "{{ ulogin2 }}"
        ssh_keys: "{{ usshkeys2 }}"
      - user_login: "{{ ulogin3 }}"
        ssh_keys: "{{ usshkeys3 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ item.0.user_login }} -- {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ user_login_with_sshkeys | ansible.builtin.subelements('ssh_keys') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.user_login }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
ok: [host1] => (item=login1) => {
    "msg": "login1 -- sshkey1"
}
ok: [host1] => (item=login3) => {
    "msg": "login3 -- sshkey31"
}
ok: [host1] => (item=login3) => {
    "msg": "login3 -- sshkey32"
}
ok: [astra175] => (item=login3) => {
    "msg": "login3 -- sshkey33"
}
```

---

Leave an empty variable:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ulogin1: login1
    usshkeys1: [sshkey1]
    ulogin2: login2
    usshkeys2: []
    ulogin3: login3
    usshkeys3:
      - sshkey31
      - sshkey32
      - sshkey33
    user_login_with_sshkeys:
#      - user_login: "{{ ulogin1 }}"
#        ssh_keys: "{{ usshkeys1 }}"
      - user_login: "{{ ulogin2 }}"
        ssh_keys: "{{ usshkeys2 }}"
#      - user_login: "{{ ulogin3 }}"
#        ssh_keys: "{{ usshkeys3 }}"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ item.0.user_login }} -- {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ user_login_with_sshkeys | ansible.builtin.subelements('ssh_keys') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.user_login }}"
```

Result:

```yaml
skipping: [host1]
```